# Uniform and absolute convergence of infinite trigonometric product

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence, infinite-product, absolute-convergence

This is an exercise given to us in our analytic number theory class:

Prove that $ \prod \cos(\tfrac{z}{2^n}) $ is uniformly and absolutely convergent on every closed disk $ \{ |z| \leq R \} $, hence its value $ P(z) $ is an analytic function on $ \mathbb{C} $. Evaluate $ P(z) $ in simple terms.

We don't have a textbook for the course. I think I need to use the Weierstrass M-test here but I am not sure how to proceed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P_n(z)=\prod_{k=1}^n \cos\left(\frac{z}{2^k}\right)$. Inductively we have
\begin{align}
P_1(z)\cdot \sin\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)&=\cos\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\sin z,\\
P_2(z)\cdot\sin\left(\frac{z}{2^2}\right)&=\cos\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)\cos \left(\frac{z}{2^2}\right)\cdot\sin\left(\frac{z}{2^2}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\cos\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2^2}\sin z ,\\
&...\\
&...\\
P_n(z)\cdot\sin\left(\frac{z}{2^n}\right)&=P_{n-1}(z)\cos\left(\frac{z}{2^n}\right)\sin\left(\frac{z}{2^n}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}P_{n-1}(z)\sin\left(\frac{z}{2^{n-1}}\right)=...=\frac{1}{2^n}\sin z .
\end{align}
Therefore we have $$
P_n(z)=\frac{1}{2^n}\frac{\sin z}{\sin\left(\frac{z}{2^n}\right)}=\frac{\sin z}{z}\cdot\frac{\frac{z}{2^n}}{\sin\left(\frac{z}{2^n}\right)}\to \frac{\sin z}{z}\quad (\, n\to \infty\,)
.$$
Thus, in simple terms, $P(z)=\frac{\sin z}{z}.$

Uniform and absolute convergence:
We can rewrite $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty \cos\left(\frac{z}{2^n}\right)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+a_n),$$
where $a_n=\frac{1}{2}\left\{\left(e^{i\frac{z}{2^n}}-1\right)+  \left(e^{-i\frac{z}{2^n}}-1\right) \right\}.$
We have for $|z|\le R$  that
\begin{align}
\left|e^{\pm i\frac{z}{2^n}}-1\right|&=\left|\frac{1}{1!}\left( \pm i\frac{z}{2^n} \right)+\frac{1}{2!}\left( \pm i\frac{z}{2^n} \right)^2+\cdots   \right|\\
&\le \left|\frac{1}{1!}\left( \frac{R}{2^n} \right)+\frac{1}{2!}\left( \frac{R}{2^n} \right)^2+\cdots   \right|\\
&=e^{\frac{R}{2^n}}-1\\
&\le \frac{e^R-1}{2^n},
\end{align}
since $e^x-1\le \frac{e^R-1}{R}\,x$ for $0\le x\le R.$
Therefore we have $|a_n|\le   \frac{e^R-1}{2^n}$ which ensures uniform and absolute convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$.